# Keymap warnings when using the "Industry Compatible" keymap on Blender 4.0

Tags: command-line, keymap

I'm using the *Industry Compatible* keymap. When I open the console, it's getting flushed with this warning:

```
WARN (wm.keymap): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v400\blender.git\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_keymap.cc:492 WM_keymap_poll: empty keymap 'Grease Pencil'
```

These disappear when I'm using the Blender native keymap.

Is there a way to get rid of those without using the Blender native keymap? I'm using the console for scripting feedback and with these warnings it's pointless.

Comment: This might be something to tell the developers about. Please use the menu Help > Report A Bug and see what they say about it.

Comment: @clawjelly Have the same problem and as a scripter, this is a showstopper. But it's solvable: Go to _Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Grease Pencil > Grease Pencil Global_ and click on _+ Add New_. This should stop the warning spamming.

Comment: @L0Lock there is a solution with pure user interaction on Blenders preferences. It that still off-topic? Voted to re-open so i can answer.

Comment: I don't have rights to reopen topics, but it wouldn't change my mind otherwise: this question still appears to be about an issue caused by a bug that the devs should solve. You posted a workaround as a comment, that's totally fine as it is.

Comment: @L0Lock ok thx. I was about to give a little more extended answer and add some screenshots.

Comment: @taiyo An answer that solves the problem or can be used as a workaround is of course welcome, but the problem should be reported as a bug so that it can be fixed.

Comment: @quellenform thx for re-opening. Of course it should be reported, didn't want to imply anything else. As i faced the same problem with the warning spam and i found no answer online i was just inclined to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning tells what's wrong, so when you navigate to *Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Grease Pencil > Grease Pencil Global* you will see that there are no keys mapped at all which causes the warning. Not sure though why this is the default setting and, as @L0Lock pointed out, should be reported (*Help > Report a Bug*). To remove the console spam, just add a key map item by pressing *+ Add New*. This already should stop the warning.

If you are a *Grease Pencil* user you might be interested in some useful key mappings. A fresh Blender 3.6 install shows two default mappings which can be taken over to 4.0. Add two new key map items, paste the command `gpencil.active_frames_delete_all` in there and edit the key commands as seen in the screenshot (*Backspace* and *Delete* respectively).

[image]